# If I cast Hail of Thorns and then Conjure Volley, would the effect of Hail of Thorns apply to the duplicate arrows created by Conjure Volley?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, ranger, ranged-attack

The description of [*hail of thorns*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hail-of-thorns) (1 minute duration, 1 bonus action casting time) says:

> The next time you hit a creature with a ranged weapon attack before the spell ends, this spell creates a rain of thorns that sprouts from your ranged weapon or ammunition. In addition to the normal effect of the attack, the target of the attack and each creature within 5 feet of it must make a Dexterity saving throw. A creature takes 1d10 piercing damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.

The description of [*conjure volley*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/conjure-volley) (instantaneous duration, 1 action casting time) says:

> You fire a piece of nonmagical ammunition from a ranged weapon or throw a nonmagical weapon into the air and choose a point within range. Hundreds of duplicates of the ammunition or weapon fall in a volley from above and then disappear. Each creature in a 40-foot-radius. 20-foot-high cylinder centered on that point must make a Dexterity saving throw. A creature takes 8d8 damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one. The damage type is the same as that of the ammunition or weapon.

**Is it possible to have a combo with *conjure volley* and *hail of thorns*, even if it takes two turns to set it up?**

For instance, I spend my first turn to cast *hail of thorns*, then use my action to stealth or something. Then, on my next turn, I cast *conjure volley*, which duplicates the arrow I cast *hail of thorns* on. The arrow isn't magical, so this should apply. I fire at a group of creatures. This should cause a hit even if the creature makes a successful saving throw.

Would this combo work?

Would I be able to combine *conjure volley* and [*ensnaring strike*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/ensnaring-strike) in a similar way?

Comment: Very related: [Can Hail of Thorns spell stack with Conjure Barrage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/98219/can-hail-of-thorns-spell-stack-with-conjure-barrage)

Answer (score 19):

## No, this would not work; *conjure volley* isn't an attack

[*Hail of thorns*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hail-of-thorns) specifies that its effects apply

> The next time you hit a creature with a ranged weapon attack

However, [*conjure volley*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/conjure-volley) does not involve a ranged weapon attack. As part of the spell, you do "fire a piece of nonmagical ammunition from a ranged weapon", but that is simply part of what triggers the spell; you are not making a ranged weapon attack against any target. Instead, *conjure volley* is a spell that forces those in the cylindrical area of effect to make a Dexterity saving throw.

[*Ensnaring strike*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/ensnaring-strike) wouldn't work with *conjure volley* for the same reason: *conjure volley* isn't a weapon attack (or an attack at all).

---

For a definition of what constitutes an "attack" (and why a spell that only involves the targets making saving throws isn't one), see the ["Making an Attack" section of the basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#MakinganAttack):

> If there's ever any question whether something you're doing counts as an attack, the rule is simple: if you're making an attack roll, you're making an attack.

Answer (score 8):

### This combo results in no special effect.

In order for the *hail of thorns* spell to activate, you have to hit with a ranged weapon attack.

> The next time you hit a creature with a ranged weapon attack before the spell ends,...

When you use *conjure volley*, you are not making a ranged weapon attack. Instead you are creating a spell effect that forces a saving throw.

> Each creature in a 40-foot-radius, 20-foot-high cylinder centered on the point must make a Dexterity save. A creature takes 8d8 damage on a failed save, or half damage on a success

For it to be a ranged weapon attack, it would have to say so. See the *booming blade* spell for an example of how this would be worded:

> As part of the action used to cast this spell, you must make a melee attack with a weapon

### What happens?

*Conjure volley* takes effect as normal duplicating your piece of ammunition. As long as you keep concentrating on *hail of thorns*, your next ranged weapon attack during the duration will trigger the spell effect.

*Hail of thorns* targets Self not the ammunition so using the ammunition for *conjure volley* doesn't impact the *hail of thorns* spell at all.