# Can the Conjure Barrage spell stack with the Disarming Attack or Trip Attack Battle Master maneuvers?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, attack, combat-maneuver

I'm new to D&D 5e. I was thinking that someone with the Martial Adept feat (which gives them 2 of the Battle Master fighter's combat maneuvers) could use their superiority die to make a thrown weapon disarm targets if used in conjunction with the *conjure barrage* spell.

The [Battle Master fighter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#BattleMaster)'s Trip Attack maneuver (PHB, p. 74) says:

> When you hit a creature with a weapon attack, you can expend one superiority die to attempt to knock the target down. You add the superiority die to the attack’s damage roll, and if the target is Large or smaller, it must make a Strength saving throw. On a failed save, you knock the target prone.

The Disarming Attack maneuver says:

> When you hit a creature with a weapon attack, you can expend one superiority die to attempt to disarm the target, forcing it to drop one item of your choice that it’s holding. You add the superiority die to the attack’s damage roll, and the target must make a Strength saving throw. On a failed save, it drops the object you choose. The object lands at its feet.

The [*conjure barrage*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/conjure-barrage) spell description (PHB, p. 225) says:

> You throw a nonmagical weapon or fire a piece of nonmagical ammunition into the air to create a cone of identical weapons that shoot forward and then disappear. Each creature in a 60-foot cone must succeed on a Dexterity saving throw. A creature takes 3d8 damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one. The damage type is the same as that of the weapon or ammunition used as a component.

Can these two work as one together? If not, why not?

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/98219/can-hail-of-thorns-spell-stack-with-conjure-barrage?rq=1

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 12):

#### These abilities do not combine.

All Maneuvers require you to "hit a creature with a weapon attack". But Conjure Barrage is not a weapon attack, it is a spell. Requiring you to use a weapon does not automatically make something a weapon attack - you need *at least* an attack roll to be able to qualify as a weapon attack and apply a Maneuver.

Then, even if you do have an ability that lets you make lots of attacks against lots of targets, you still wouldn't be able to multi-disarm anyone. You can only use a single Maneuver per attack, and it triggers off of "hitting with a weapon attack", so you'd need to pick a single target to suffer the disarm and extra damage.

Comment: Similarly, @BrentLissoway, this is likely why _booming blade_ and _green-flame blade_ have the awkward phrase `melee attack with a weapon` in their description: the term "weapon attack" is a mechanical term with a specific meaning.